# Looping for a random number of times java

Tags: java, loops, random

My problem is that I need to produce a random number, which is fine I've done that part, but then I need to use that random number to loop.

So for example if the random number was 13, then loop a piece of code 13 times.

I've had a mess around and haven't managed to get anything working and haven't been able to find anything online to help me.

Basically what I'm trying to find out if this is even possible?

thanks guys.

Comment: I guess you did not search enough, what do you think about this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm. We are not suposed to do your homework. Do your efort first and let us check your code.

Comment: [It's impossibru!](https://reposti.com/i/m/bMm.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple `for` loop:

```
for (int i = new Random().nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic Java. You have a number that you get once you randomize. Just use it in a `while` loop or a `for` loop.

```
int x = GetRandomNumber(); //You have stated you have already done this...
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
 //Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = random.nextInt(); // As you said, you got this so far...
while (a > 0) { // if you need your random number for something, just copy its value to new variable and place it here instead of a
    // some code
    a--;

}
```